# Is there a clean way to replicate sequential variable assignments in SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to replicate a SAS process in SQL and am having some trouble finding a clean way to emulate sequential variable assignments.

For example (Where a,b, and c are fields):

```
IF a > b THEN
    a = '1'
ELSE a = '2'
END IF
If a = '2' AND b = '3' THEN 
    a = '1' AND
    b = '1'
END IF
IF a = '1' AND b = '2' THEN
    c = 'yady-yada-yada'
END IF
```

This was a GREATLY simplified example, ideally I'd try to break out the logic, but that is prohibitively complex.  I know that I can use dummy aliases and case statements, or a sequence of UPDATEs.

ex:

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
  WHEN a > b THEN '1'
  ELSE '2'
 END as a0
,CASE 
  WHEN a0 = '2' AND b = '3' THEN '1'
  ELSE a0
 END as a1
,CASE 
  WHEN a0 = '2' AND b = '3' THEN '1'
  ELSE b
 END as b0
,CASE 
  WHEN a1 = '2' AND b0 = '3' THEN 'yada-yada-yada'
  ELSE NULL
 END as c
....
FROM someTable
```

There are problems with an 'Insufficient memory for plastic steps' error with this approach though.

I feel like there has to be a cleaner way to approach this though, in any other language the logic is very simple but it's turning out to be a nightmare in SQL.

Comment: Are these variables or columns?  It is unclear what SQL really has to do with a problem of assigning values to scalar variables.  You might also want to edit your question and show one (or more) of the methods you have considered, so we have some idea of what you consider unclean.

Comment: They are columns.  I apologize that this is a poorly phrased question - I tried googling 'Procedural logic in SQL' but I just got results on cursors.  But that is exactly the problem, SAS is able to treat fields like mutable arrays and I'm having a lot of trouble doing the same in a query.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way is using a series of CTEs:

```
with t1 as (
      select t.*,
             (case when a > b then '1' else '2' end) as a
      from sometable t
     ),
     t2 as (
      select . . .,
             (case when a = '2' and b = '3' then '1' else a end) as a,
             (case when a = '2' and b = '3' then '1' else b end) as b
      from t1
     ),
     t3 as (
      select . . .
             (case when a = '1' and b = '2' then 'yady-yada-yada' end) as c
      from t2
     )
select *
from t3;
```

However, I would recommend that you try to simplify the logic.  SQL is not quite as simple as a series of conditional statements.  But, there are often simpler ways than converting that logic to a series of (essentially) nested `case` statements.